# how to display the customer name after confirming via email in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, header

[image]

When **confirming account via email getting this, it is not showing customer name**

but **it's shows only when I logged in (displaying customer name)** .

I want to show customer name after confirming account via email.

how I can solve this ....